# How to get rid of special characters in the output of make

Tags: terminal, locale, character-encoding

When I run gcc, it outputs errors but the function names are surrounded by special characters   like this 
â€˜setup_connectionâ€™:

This same is repeated with variable names. I am wondering if the terminal settings have to be changed. I am currently using ssh to login to the machine.

Any inputs valuable

Comment: what terminal and font are you using? Have you tried to set the font to console for example?
Also check the locale that your system is using.

Comment: This `â€` looks like UTF-8 as shown on a non-UTF-8 terminal. Try other values for the `LANG` variable.

Comment: It really seems that the system is using a locale that's not supported by the terminal / terminal emulator being used, in this case UTF-8 in something that's treating it as iso8859-15. Fix your terminal, or use a locale that it supports.

Comment: # locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"

Comment: The output of the locale command shows that this is a UTF-8 terminal.  Is there any other setting I have to do. Thanks for the answers

Comment: Exactly what terminal/terminal emulator are you using. You never mentioned it...

Comment: Sorry, it is Xshell 4 (build 0128)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- configure your ssh client to accept UTF-8 (PuTTY can do this)
- force 'C' locale: `export LC_ALL=C`